# How to call a normal python function along with header information without using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, python-decorators, request-headers

**Details of application:**

UI: Angular

Backend: Python Flask (using Swagger)

Database: MongoDB

We have a few backend python methods which will be called from the UI side to do CURD operations on the database.
Each of the methods has a decorator which will check the header information to ensure that only a genuine person can call the methods.

From the UI side when these API's are called, this authorization  decorator is not creating any problem and a proper response is returned to the UI (as we are passing the header information also to the request)

But now we are writing unit test cases for the API's. Here each test case will call the backend method and because of the authorization decorator, I am getting errors and not able to proceed. How can I handle this issue?

```
backend_api.py
--------------
from commonlib.auth import require_auth

@require_auth
def get_records(record_id):
    try:
        record_details = records_coll.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(str(record_id))})
        if record_details is not None:
            resp = jsonify({"msg": "Found Record", "data": str(record_details)})
            resp.status_code = 200
            return resp
        else:
            resp = jsonify({"msg": "Record not found"})
            resp.status_code = 404
            return resp
    except Exception as ex:
        resp = jsonify({"msg": "Exception Occured",'Exception Details': ex}))
        resp.status_code = 500
        return resp



commonlib/auth.py
-----------------

### some lines of code here

def require_auth(func):
    """
    Decorator that can be added to a function to check for authorization
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(*args,**kwargs)
        username = get_username()
        security_log = {
            'loginId': username,
            'securityProtocol': _get_auth_type(),
        }

        try:
            if username is None:
                raise SecurityException('Authorization header or cookie not found')
            if not is_auth_valid():
                raise SecurityException('Authorization header or cookie is invalid')

        except SecurityException as ex:
            log_security(result='DENIED', message=str(ex))
            unauthorized(str(ex))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


test_backend_api.py
-------------------

class TestBackendApi(unittest.TestCase):

    ### some lines of code here
    @mock.patch("pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one", side_effect=[projects_json])
    def test_get_records(self, mock_call):

        from backend_api import get_records

        ret_resp = get_records('61729c18afe7a83268c6c9b8')
        final_response = ret_resp.get_json()

        message1 = "return response status code is not 200"

        self.assertEqual(ret_resp.status_code, 200, message1)

Error snippet :
---------------
E           RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
E
E           This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
E           an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
E           information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Comment: A lot of unit tests just set the user object to authorized before calling the endpoint. Just as one example, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication